# Jquery SMarttextbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox

```
  <table width="1000px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" >
    <tr>
      <td>
        <form name="addtravel_form" id="addtravel_form" action="searchresult.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <table width="1000px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" class="box">
            <tr bgcolor="#DADADA">
              <td class="bline" colspan='2'>
                <div  class="px12 boldfont black fontarial"></div>
              </td>
              <td align="right" class="bline">
                <div class="px12 boldfont black fontarial">Step : 1</div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="fontarial brown px12" style="width:250px;">
                Departure month
              </td>
              <td colspan='2'>
                <div id="tour_departuremonthdiv">
                  <input type="text" name="tour_departuremonth" id="tour_departuremonth" style="padding-left:4px; padding-top:4px;" value="" class="lgtxt" size='27' />
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form> 
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="admin/js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="admin/js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="admin/js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="admin/js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" href="admin/demos.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
  <link charset="utf-8" media="screen" type="text/css" href="admin/SmartTextBox.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
  <script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="admin/SmartTextBox.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="admin/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="admin/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="admin/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#tour_departuremonth").smartTextBox({
        autocompleteUrl: "admin/create_daymonths.php",
        onlyAutocomplete: true,
        uniqueValues: true,
        debug: true
      });

      $('#tour_departuremonthdiv').live('mouseout', function() {
        alert($("#tour_departuremonth").val());
        inint();
      });

      function inint() {
        var tour_departuremonths = $("#tour_departuremonth").val();
        //alert(tour_departuremonths);
        alert('month'+tour_departuremonths);
      }
    });
  </script>
```

The problem is that if I typed "apr 2010", the alert box does not show it the first time but if i later typed "may 2010" then only "apr 2010" shows up on the alert.

However if I do a mouseout, it works perfectly well expcept that everytime I do a mouseout the alert shows up... Ideally the event should fire only when I change the values in smartbox.

Any ideas why it does not work?

Please note that i have three smart boxes in a form. The other two smartboxes work perfectly fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your first alert is within a **mouseout** event, and will therfore only be shown when the corresponding event is triggered.